# I have a problem in plotting simple Exponential Equation?

Tags: plotting, webmathematica

The simple piece of Code is given below.

```
kB = 8.617*10^-5   ;(* ev/k*)
Ea = 20*10^-3   ;(* ev*)
e = 1.6*10^-19   ;
h = 4.1*10^-15   ;
G0 = 10*e^2/h;
G = G0*E^(Ea/(kB*t));
Plot[%, {(t^-1), 0.004, 0.01}]
```

I want to plot G on y_axis corresponding to "1/t" on x_axis. 
I am getting an error ***"Tag Power in 1/t is Protected."***

Comment: The syntax you used is not correct.  `t^-1` cannot be used as a variable in `Plot`, only simple symbols can.  Try `ParametricPlot[{t^-1, G}, {t, ...}]` or replace `t` by `1/x` in `G` (`ReplaceAll`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
kB = 8.617*10^-5;(*ev/k*)
Ea = 20*10^-3;(*ev*)
e = 1.6*10^-19;
h = 4.1*10^-15;
G0 = 10*e^2/h;
G1[x_] := G0*E^(Ea*x/kB);
Plot[G1[x], {x, 0.004, 0.01}]
```

[image]

Have fun!